# Display field with the same format in HTML email

Tags: html, format

I was using email templates feature but for internal reasons we had to move it to custom class.
Now I am creating an email template on HTML code on an APEX class.
The thing is that when I insert the Case. Description field, its not inserted with the correct format like it was happening on the email template.
Expected:
[image]

What am I receiving on the email sent:

[image]

this is the part of the code that insert the description field:

```
body += '<html><body>';
body += '<div style="font-style: italic;">' + newCase.Description + '</div>';
body += '</body></html>';
mail.setHtmlBody(body);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like line break `<br>` tags are missing. But first is your description field a text field or a rich text field? You can add a custom description field which will be Rich text field and use that here `body += '<div style="font-style: italic;">' + newCase.Description__c + '</div>';`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it didnt work. I've added a custom field with Rich Text Area(32768) type, copied the value from the Case Description (which is filled automatically on the Email-to-Case creation)
The results were the same

Comment: No no lift and shift wont work here. You will have to form the data with `<br>` tags then save that in Rich text area. Can you share the DB value of the custom field which you created?

Comment: I cannot do that, like I've said, this field is filled automatically on the Email-to-Case creation (and contains the requester email's body). On the email template I just used this {!Case.Description} and it came formatted properly

Comment: Ok, but now u said you were using apex right? Then you can do that right? or try to use `newCase.Description.unescapeHTML3 or 4`.

Comment: same results doing
newCase.Description.unescapeHtml3()
or 
newCase.Description.unescapeHtml4()